# Include date time within PowerShell string

Tags: powershell

I'm currently separating my PowerShell functions out into a separate location.

Is there a way to include the $LogFileNameTimeStamp within the below function so that I do not have to declare it separately?

```
$LogFileNameTimeStamp = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f (GET-DATE)

Function Log-File-Append
{
    Param ([string]$logstring)
    Add-content $LogFileLocation\$LogFileNameTimeStamp"_log.log" -value $logstring
}
```

I have tried this, following an answer on another Stack Overflow post:

```
Add-content $LogFileLocation\"$($theDate.ToString('u'))_log.log" -value $logstring
```

But this returns the error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

I'm still finding my feet with PowerShell so any pointers would be gratefully received.

Comment: It looks like $theDate migt be null. You could try running this in the Powershell ISE and add a breakpoint before the statement, checking if this particular variable is null or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $LogFileLocation is a valid path the following should work

```
Function Log-File-Append
{
    Param ([string]$logstring)
    Add-Content "$LogFileLocation\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))_log.log" -value $logstring
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .NET [System.IO.Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to form a valid Windows path instead of doing it manually.

```
Add-content ([IO.Path]::Combine($LogFileLocation,(("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f (GET-DATE)) + "_log.log"))) -value $logstring
```